# Avoid recomputing size of all Cloud Storage files in Beam Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working on a pipeline that reads ~5 million files from a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) directory. I have it configured to run on Google Cloud Dataflow.

The problem is that when I start the pipeline, it takes hours "computing the size" of all of the files:

```
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished computing size of: 10000 files
[...]
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished computing size of: 5480000 files
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 5483720 files in 5549.38778591156 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished computing size of: 10000 files
[...]
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished computing size of: 5480000 files
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 5483720 files in 7563.196493148804 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished computing size of: 10000 files
[...]
```

As you can see, it took an hour an a half (5549 seconds) to compute the size of about 5.5M files, then it started all over again from the beginning! It took another 2 hours to run the second pass, then it started it a third time! As of this time of writing, the job is still not available in the Dataflow console, which leads me to believe this is all happening on my local machine and not taking advantage of any distributed computing.

When I test the pipeline with a smaller input dataset (2 files) it repeats the size estimation 4 times:

```
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 2 files in 0.33771586418151855 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 2 files in 0.1244659423828125 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 2 files in 0.13422417640686035 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Starting the size estimation of the input
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio:Finished listing 2 files in 0.14139890670776367 seconds.
```

At this rate it will take about 8 hours just to perform GCS size estimations of all 5.5M files 4 times, all before the Dataflow job has even started.

My pipeline is configured with the `--runner=DataflowRunner` option, so it should be running in Dataflow:

```
python bigquery_import.py --runner=DataflowRunner #other options...
```

The pipeline reads from GCS like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--input',
    required=True,
    help='Input Cloud Storage directory to process.')
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    files = p | beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://project/dir/*.har.gz')
```

Refer to [bigquery_import.py](https://github.com/rviscomi/bigquery/blob/8ac58f72a2367305d080e406e81ef376db8a90f7/dataflow/python/bigquery_import.py#L208-L212) on GitHub for the full code.

I'm confused why this tedious process is happening outside of the Dataflow environment and why it needs to be done multiple times. Am I reading the files from GCS correctly or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: FWIW I'm updating an old Dataflow Java SDK implementation which does not have this issue. Source code for reference: https://github.com/HTTPArchive/bigquery/blob/master/dataflow/java/src/main/java/com/httparchive/dataflow/BigQueryImport.java#L396-L400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Beam have two transforms for reading text. `ReadFromText` and `ReadAllFromText`. `ReadFromText` will run into this issue but `ReadAllFromText` shouldn't.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L438

Downside of `ReadAllFromText` is that it won't perform dynamic work rebalancing, but this should not be an issue when reading a a large number of files.

Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9620 for tracking issues with ReadFromText (and file-based sources in general).

Comment: Sounds promising! Changing to `ReadAllFromText` causes the pipeline to fail now with a `'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'` attribute error on the subsequent transform step that JSON-parses the files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got it working by changing `p | beam.io.ReadFromText(gcs_path)` to `p | beam.Create([gcs_path]) | beam.io.ReadAllFromText()`. The two notable changes being: pass a list containing the glob string to the ReadAllFromText method instead. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I am trying to process 15M files. I used recommended pipeline `p | beam.Create([gcs_path]) | beam.io.ReadAllFromText()`. The result is that Dataflow indeed spawns immediately, but the ReadAllFromText takes forever to compute. I can see in logs that for several hours it tries to compute the size of files. It already took like 8h+ and it just finished computing size of ~2M out of 15M files. 

How can I avoid computing those sizes? What is even rationale of doing so? I could perfectly write my own transformation that lists all 15M links instantly form GCS and read it in next step.