# Confusing error on Apache Beam's FileBasedSource when running pipeline on Google Dataflow over ~2.4M files on GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline running on Google Dataflow, that reads gzip-compressed JSON data from GCS, transforms them, and loads them into Google BigQuery. The pipeline works as expected on a sample batch of data, but when I try to run it over the whole data (~2.4M files), it sometimes raises a confusing error that cracks the process after a few occurrences.

The error is:

> Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 961, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 553, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1095, in
> apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py",
> line 380, in process source =
> list(source.split(float('inf')))[0].source IndexError: list index out
> of range During handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py",
> line 647, in do_work work_executor.execute() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py",
> line 179, in execute op.start() File
> "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 63, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 64, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 79, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 80, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 84, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 332, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 261, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 268, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 332, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 963, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1030, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 961, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 553, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1122, in
> apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 963, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1030, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 961, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 553, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1122, in
> apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 195, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 670, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 671, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 963, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1045, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/**init**.py",
> line 446, in raise_with_traceback raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
> File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 961, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 553, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1095, in
> apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py",
> line 380, in process source =
> list(source.split(float('inf')))[0].source IndexError: list index out
> of range [while running 'GetData/ReadAllFiles/ReadRange']

I understand that the stage involved in the error is `GetData`:

```py
files = (p
         | 'Init' >> beam.Create([files_pattern])
         | 'GetData' >> ReadAllFromText())
```

Where `p` is the pipeline object and `files_pattern` is a glob of the form `gs://{bucket}/{prefix}/*.json.gz`.

The error is confusing to me because it says nothing about the pipeline itself, and remember the fact that it works for the sample batch.

My process is very similar to the one in [Avoid recomputing size of all Cloud Storage files in Beam Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874942/avoid-recomputing-size-of-all-cloud-storage-files-in-beam-python-sdk). I checked the mentioned resources there, but I still can't manage my error. What am I missing here? I couldn't find any resources about this error in specific.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in filebasedsource.  Two questions: first, do you have any empty files?  Second, can you try setting min_bundle_size=1 on your ReadAllFromText setting?

Comment: Yes, I checked that there are some empty files. I could try with `min_bundle_size=1`, what should I expect by changing the default?

Comment: The problem here looks like bug in ReadAllFromText.  The issue is that when it splits the work up across the workers, it will crash if one of those splits is empty.  min_bundle_size=1 should prevent that from happening, but not otherwise impact the job much

Comment: Ok. I'll try with that value then and be back with news.

Comment: I reran the process using `min_bundle_size=1` in `ReadAllFromText`, and the same error is still happening. :(

Comment: I tested the pipeline with a tiny batch of data. I added a zero bytes JSON file, which has a size of 33 bytes after compression (gzip), and no error is happening. There are ten files in the batch, and only nine get through the `GetData` stage, as expected.

Comment: @danielm I also tested with a sample batch of 100k files and the pipeline succeeded, it worked as expected.

Comment: Can you try running with this patch that adds additional logging ? I wonder if FileSystem.match() call is flaky and sometimes return and empty result where a glob has a very large number of files - https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/12363

Comment: @chamikara Could you tell me how can I use that on Google Cloud Dataflow or link some info about it?

Comment: Instructions are here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BEAM/Python+Tips. This implementation is shared by all runners so you should be able to reproduce with DirectRunner (writing to GCS) as well.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work? It sounds like there's some bad file it's tripping up on, but it's unclear which (or why). You could try running with subsets like `gs://{bucket}/{prefix}/[a-m]*.json.gz` to identify the bad file(s) and then try to run over them locally which would aid in debugging.

Comment: @robertwb I couldn't get this done perfectly. I tried that approach, passing groups of files using different globs. I was able to load 1.9 M files (~177M records) into BigQuery. I tried groups of 100K files at most, and only 5/24 of them failed. I think the process catches data corruption very well. I also tested a Java SDK template (word counts) over one of the failed groups, and it worked with no problems, so I'm suspecting of implementation errors in the Python SDK.

Comment: If you could narrow it to the specific bad file(s), that would be very helpful for filing a bug report and actually getting this fixed.

Comment: If there is a bug in the Python SDK (very possible) it would be good to fix (even if it's corrupt file handling). Do you have an example of a file that works with Java but not Python?

Comment: @robertwb, I haven't identified the files for which the process failed. I know which the 100k-files groups that failed are. Handling this issue is in my work pipeline but with less priority now than other tasks, so that I'll be working on it later.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [Dataflow Shuffle](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#benefits-of-dataflow-shuffle). Instead of having the shuffle data in the VM's persistent disks, the data is kept in Dataflow backend. As the error message mentions the index being out of range and, from the comments, the job ran using less data what happens is that you run out of memory or storage.

Furthermore, keep in mind that you can use [Dataflow Google provided templates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates). Keep in mind that these templates are in Java rather than Python. One of the templates is GCS Text to BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check Dataflow Shuffle. I decided not to use the templates because I know nothing about Java, and the pipeline has side outputs and some stages where it is extracting and transforming the data. I have to do the testing proposed by @chamikara in the comments; but now, the project has less priority in my pipeline.

Comment: I've been running the process for the last 6 hours using Dataflow Shuffle and it is still throwing the same error, but now the process is not halted.

Comment: After some point, the process halted after reaching 4 errors in a single worker.

Comment: I think this error is orthogonal to the choice of shuffle engine.